# Ошибка 'datetime.datetime' object is not iterable

Tags: python, массивы, numpy, datetime

подскажите, почему возникает эта ошибка и как можно ее исправить?

---

Кратко введу в то, что здесь происходит.

Необходимо было набор данных из файла загрузить в numpy (да, для этого есть pandos, но по заданию использовать его нельзя). Данные в файле представлены в виде: "дата, цифра, цифра, цифра", но все это, естественно, строки. Было принято решение использовать структурированный массив Numpy. И вот нужно мне теперь конвертировать строку с датой в формат даты, но что-то не выходит. Не могу понять, в чем проблема.

---

```
with open('file.csv') as f:
    t_array = np.empty([s,1], dtype = [('Date', '<U10'), ('param1', 'i4'), ('param2', 'i4'), ('param3', 'i4')])

with open('austin_weather.csv') as f:
    i = 0
    for line in f:
        str_list = line.split(',')
        t_array[i] = (str_list[0], str_list[1], str_list[2], str_list[3]) 
        i=i+1

for t in t_array['Date']:
     date_list.append(list(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(t), '[\'%Y-%m-%d\']')))
```

Comment: Зачем ты пытаешься конвертировать дату в список?

Comment: @Эникейщик Мне нужно использовать дату как один из параметров для построения графика. Поэтому создаю список с датами. Можно как-то иначе сделать? Готов послушать варианты

Comment: В самой последней строчке ты пытаешься конвертировать **одну** дату в список. Что ты ожидаешь на выходе?

Comment: Убери оттуда list в общем.

Comment: @Эникейщик ой, действительно. Благодарю, как-то не дошло сразу))